# Retrieving data from database and displaying? IOS

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, cocoapods

I'm new in Firebase and the Pods. I'm having trouble retrieving data from the Database. I think I'm doing something wrong with the libraries that Firebase has. My app runs good but doesn't show the results in the console, can someone explain why is not getting the information from my database. As well any resource from a different server will help a lot. Here is what I have.

[image: This is my code]

[image: This is the last one image (click)]

PS: Any other information let me know Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have error in the log? Can you add a breakpoint in the `chidAdded`?

Comment: @Kerberos I add the breakpoint and seems doing ok !! No error

Comment: the observer will only be executed when a new child is added. Where do you add a new item? And IF the observer is hit, what is inside the snapshotValue?

Comment: @Milander the data is already added, I didn’t added data in my code. I want to retrieve the information, and if observer is hit the lon and lat is the one suppose to be inside of the dictionary!!

Comment: You should try to change .childAdded to another type like .value, .childAdded is only called when a new child is added =)

Comment: @Milander I try .value but in the console shows like 100 lines of different codes and logs!! I’m doing something wrong and I don’t know where to Start !! :(

Comment: Show us the logs =)

Comment: @Milander there is some logs from the console !!

Comment: The logs that are showing are the Firebase debug logs. This is good, because this means that the app is connected to the firebase. To disable those logs you could remove the  -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled in the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

As first you should change your observer DateType to .value, because the .childAdded will only be executed when a child is added.

Second you should loop through all your 'bestBuyLocations?' and fetch the lat and lons.

see example below:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("bestBuy")
databaseRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
    if let snapShotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
        for location in snapShotValue {

            if let locationValues = location.value as? [String: Any] {
                if let lon = locationValues["lon"] as? NSString {
                    print(lon)
                }

                if let lat = locationValues["lat"] as? NSString {
                    print(lat)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I change the datatype to .value and I try looping the data that I have on my database and still not showing in the console !!! Should I delete the dictionary and get the data individually?

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint inside the observe method and check if the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: Nice! Good to hear that!

Comment: Oh sorry for the late response. Can you tell me what is inside of the snapShotValue when the breakpoint is hit?

Answer (score -1):

As per your attached image it is firestore not realtime database. The code you have added is for real-time database. please check firestore documentation to retrieve data.